# Drupal use JQuery/JavaScript to load a page in drupal in new window

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, window.open

I want that on a click of a link in drupal page I open a new window which has a form in it. But the window should be a new window.

How could I do it.?

I was thinking of using a regular

```
window.open(theURL, windowName, features);
```

but how do I

```
1) Create a drupal page without the default themes.

2) Load this page from JS into a new window. This page is going to be a form.
```

Should I create just a tpl page and load it through _theme function? I am confused...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the Drupal way... but to answer your questions:

1) You don't create drupal pages without themes. You could create an html form without Drupal in sites/all/forms/

2) `$('#element').attr('target', '_blank');`